# ¿Cómo uso reshape o reshape2?

Tags: r, data

Tengo un df así

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c('SS940426', 'SS940442', 'SS952672'),
                 Estación = c('200510020012', '200380030004', '200180010105'),
                 control= c(1, 2, 3),
                 Peso=c(250,380,410),
                 campo1= c(520,982,988),
                 campo2= c(682,987,988),
                 campo3= c(720,963,999))


df

      ID         Estacion       Control    Peso    Campo1  Campo2  Campo3
1  SS940426    200510020012      1          250      520    682    720
2  SS940442    200380030004      2          380      482    987    993
3  SS952672    200180010105      3          410      588    688    999
```

Y quiero que tener uno que sea así:

```
      ID         Estacion       Control    Peso     
1  SS940426    200510020012      1          250      
2  SS940426    200510020012      2          520
3  SS940426    200510020012      3          682
4  SS940426    200510020012      4          720
5  SS940442    200380030004      1          380
6  SS940442    200380030004      2          482         
7  SS940442    200380030004      3          987
8  SS940442    200380030004      4          993
9  SS952672    200180010105      1          410     
10  SS952672    200180010105     2          588
10  SS952672    200180010105     3          688
10  SS952672    200180010105     3          699
```

Se hacerlo en SAS usando proc transpose pero en R no sé cómo hacerlo. Estoy usando melt del paquete reshape2 pero no sé cómo escribir el script adecuadamente. También he intentado usando reshape pero no sé cómo se hace.

```
df1<-melt(DF, value.name = ????, id.vars = c("control","peso")
     +                   variable.name = ????)
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `reshape()` puedes pasar de un formato "ancho" a uno "largo":

```
new_df <- reshape(data=df, 
          direction="long", 
          varying=list(4:7),
          timevar="Control", 
          idvar=1:3
          )[,-3]
```

Salida `new_df`:

```
                              ID     Estación Control Peso
SS940426.200510020012.1 SS940426 200510020012       1  250
SS940442.200380030004.1 SS940442 200380030004       1  380
SS952672.200180010105.1 SS952672 200180010105       1  410
SS940426.200510020012.2 SS940426 200510020012       2  520
SS940442.200380030004.2 SS940442 200380030004       2  982
SS952672.200180010105.2 SS952672 200180010105       2  988
SS940426.200510020012.3 SS940426 200510020012       3  682
SS940442.200380030004.3 SS940442 200380030004       3  987
SS952672.200180010105.3 SS952672 200180010105       3  988
SS940426.200510020012.4 SS940426 200510020012       4  720
SS940442.200380030004.4 SS940442 200380030004       4  963
SS952672.200180010105.4 SS952672 200180010105       4  999
```

La parte importante de la llamada a `reshape()` es:

- Obviamente `direction="long"` para indicar que la salida será un formato largo
- `varying=list(4:7)` con el cual establecemos que columnas se transportarán a una forma vertical, en nuestro ejemplo, las 4 últimas.

Dos cosas secundarias son distintas al ejemplo que diste: `reshape()` generó un `rowname` defindido por el parámetro `idvar=1:3` y el orden, que es ligeramente distinto a tu ejemplo, corregirlo es sencillo:

```
new_df <- new_df[order(new_df$ID, new_df$Estación),]
rownames(new_df) <- NULL
```

Y ahora sí:

```
         ID     Estación Control Peso
1  SS940426 200510020012       1  250
2  SS940426 200510020012       2  520
3  SS940426 200510020012       3  682
4  SS940426 200510020012       4  720
5  SS940442 200380030004       1  380
6  SS940442 200380030004       2  982
7  SS940442 200380030004       3  987
8  SS940442 200380030004       4  963
9  SS952672 200180010105       1  410
10 SS952672 200180010105       2  988
11 SS952672 200180010105       3  988
12 SS952672 200180010105       4  999
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el paquete ´dplyr´ como sigue:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df,NAME,Peso,4:7)%>%select(-NAME)
         ID     Estación control Peso
1  SS940426 200510020012       1  250
2  SS940442 200380030004       2  380
3  SS952672 200180010105       3  410
4  SS940426 200510020012       1  520
5  SS940442 200380030004       2  982
6  SS952672 200180010105       3  988
7  SS940426 200510020012       1  682
8  SS940442 200380030004       2  987
9  SS952672 200180010105       3  988
10 SS940426 200510020012       1  720
11 SS940442 200380030004       2  963
12 SS952672 200180010105       3  999
```

Puedes checar esta hoja de ayuda para aprender hacer otras cosas similares:https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/data-wrangling-spanish.pdf